# How to tell how many frames a MovieClip spans on timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

We have an effect we like to use where we synchronize a series of slides with a sound. As the sound plays, we show each slide (which is its own frame in a MovieClip), and slowly scale the slide up to provide a little bit of movement. Our sounds tend to be equivalent to one frame on the parent timeline, so we look to see what sound is playing for that frame to calculate how long each slide should be displayed for.

The issue we have is that occasionally we need to "stretch" one of these animations across two or more slides, which means we need to look ahead and calculate the slide length based on the combined length of the sounds during the span of frames where the MovieClip that contains the slide images is displayed.

However, I haven't been able to find a property that tells me how many timeline frames a MovieClip is displayed for (note that this would be different from totalframes, the number of frames that clip *contains*). Is it just wishful thinking that such a property exists, or can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the problem correctly but have you tried MovieClip.currentFrame?

Comment: So, when the MovieClip with the animation triggers ADDED_TO_STAGE, the currentFrame would be the frame where the _first_ frame of the span of frames where that animation is displayed appears. If that animation is on, say, three frames on the timeline of its parent, can you clarify how knowing the currentFrame value would be an aide to knowing that the animation appears on three consecutive frames? I'm not following your logic at all.

Comment: Ok, I need more clarification about where the sound is and the way you organized your timeline. Your description doesn't give me any idea. Why is sound on one frame? Why are you stretching the animations?

Comment: When we enter the frame, we play a sound. When the sound is done, we often (but not always) advance to the next frame. Storyboards are organized around "events", where the intention is that each event will = 1 sound. However, sometimes the sound file winds up being broken into two or more sounds/frames, for instance if we're building a bulleted list, the sound would be broken into several and each "bullet" would be on its own frame (mainly for synchronization reasons). However, the original sequence of images would be used unaltered, spanning multiple frames. Not sure the why of this matters.

Comment: The why of this matters because I don't have a visual reference and that would help a lot. However, I understand the problem better now. I'm not sure why you are doing this on timeline with events and stretched movieclips but obviously, unlike the intention, 1 sound is not equal one event. I'm assuming on each frame you know which movieclip is playing so the answer to "how many timeline frames a MovieClip is displayed for" would be to use as many frames in parent timeline as your movieclip so they are synchronized. So 3 frames in movieclip, 3 frames span in the parent timeline.

Comment: That's not a workable solution, since the code needs to work no matter who built the timeline content. Thanks for the attempt, though. It's more than anyone else stepped forward with.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a class like this, which will keep track of the amount of frames it has been present on the DisplayList:

```
package
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class ExtMovieClip extends MovieClip
    {

        // Properties.
        private var _lifetime:int = 0;


        // Constructor.
        public function ExtMovieClip()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _added);
        }


        // Was added to the DisplayList.
        private function _added(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _added);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _track);
            addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, _removed);
        }


        // Was removed from the DisplayList.
        private function _removed(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, _removed);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _track);

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _added);
        }


        // Increment the lifetime of this MovieClip.
        public function _track(e:Event):void
        {
            _lifetime ++;
        }


        // Retunrns the lifetime of this MovieClip.
        public function get lifetime():int
        {
            return _lifetime;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I need to know as soon as it hits the Display List how many frames it will span, so I know how many sounds to give it to listen to.